# How to combine Laravel validation required_if and required_without_all rules?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a situation with a subscription form, which must have different validation rules depending on user selection.
I almost complete this, but I'm stuck in a point which need a combination of rules that I think I can't get with predefined laravel rules.

As shown in the following chart, the point is when a user select invoicing preferences, with options **Digital** and **Printed**, if user option is **Printed** I need at least one physical address, so street address field group **OR** district address fields group must be mandatory.

[image: Flow chart related to conditional validation I need to achieve]

Mandatory field **unless** other field is filled can be achieved by `required_without_all`rule, so I've trying with no success, a combination of `required_if` and `required_without_all`rules, like the following example:

```
public function rules()
{
return [
...
    'invoicing_preferences' => 'required',
    'invoicing_email' => 'email|required_if:invoicing_preferences,digital',
    'invoicing_street_name' => 'string|required_if:invoicing_preferences,printed|required_without_all:invoicing_district,invoicing_parcel',
    'invoicing_street_number' => 'number|required_if:invoicing_preferences,printed|required_without_all:invoicing_district,invoicing_parcel',
    'invoicing_street_flat' => 'number|required_if:invoicing_preferences,printed|required_without_all:invoicing_district,invoicing_parcel',
    'invoicing_street_dep' => 'alpha_num|required_if:invoicing_preferences,printed|required_without_all:invoicing_district,invoicing_parcel',
    'invoicing_district' => 'alpha_num|required_if:invoicing_preferences,printed|required_without_all:invoicing_street_name, invoicing_street_number; invoicing_street_flat,invoicing_street_dep',
    'invoicing_parcel' => 'alpha_num|required_if:invoicing_preferences,printed|required_without_all:invoicing_street_name, invoicing_street_number; invoicing_street_flat,invoicing_street_dep',

...
    ];
}
```

This combination doesn't work because **always** results in the `required_with_all`rule no matter if I've checked **digital** at the first point.

Answer (score 1):

The `rules()` method is **a method** that is expected to return array of rules. Why would I write about such an obvious thing? Well, **insert any kind of validation logic inside it**, which means that it can also do some evaluation of posted data and gradually build up the returning array.

```
public function rules()
{
    $this; // holds information about request itself with all the data POST-ed

    if (something) {
        return []; // something is true...
    }

    return []; // default behaviour (ehm, something is not true)
}
```

---

Another similar approach is to use multiple arrays and in the end merge them together (build them up). Which may result in nicer code. Also do not be afraid of using one or two private methods to clean up the code.

Comment: Thank you Kyslik, this project is actually freezed so I didn't read your reply till now.
I will try your suggestion for the sake of learning.